# URL amigável com JSF, Facelets e Bootstrap é possível?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2.2

Estou usando em um projeto JSF com Facelets e Bootstrap. Como deixa-lo com URL amigável?

Exemplo:
Após o login a URL fica assim: **exemplo.com/public/home.xhtml**
Ao clicar em um item doo menu a URL muda para: **exemplo.com/public/cadastro.xhtml**

É possível deixar a URL fixa, como: **exemplo.com**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o PrettyFaces você consegue fazer isso, [link aqui](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

Exemplo de configuração dado pelo site:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="login">
        <pattern value="/login" />
        <view-id value="/legacy/user/login.jsp" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que queria! Apesar de ainda não conseguir fazer funcionar.

Comment: Também tive um dificuldade para implementar no começo, mas tem alguns tutorias na internet que da pra ter uma noção melhor.

Comment: Também não consegui fazer o pretty faces funcionar aqui. alguém pode então indicar um tutorial que explique melhor? essa configuração basica do site do pretty faces não surtiu efeito